# inconsistent table number

Tags: tables, numbering, longtable

I have the following problem: I placed two tables of the same kind following each other but the second table has inconsistent number: The first table has the number `2.1` (chapter 2, Nr. of the table 1) and the second table has the number `2.3`

My example follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{semtrans}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\chapter{The analyzed roots and verbs}
\label{chap-AnalyzedRootsAndVerbs}
\chapter{Root S\Alif L `ask (for)'}
\label{chap-RootS'L}

\section{Verbal types and tokens of the root S\Alif L in the Qur'an}
\label{sec-Types and Tokens of the root S'L}


\section{The root in the Dictionaries of CA}
\label{S'L_in_CA_Dictionaries}

\section{Form I – the verb \textit{sa\Alif ala} `ask (for)'}
\label{FormI_sa'ala_ask(for)}

\subsection{Semantic roles of the verb \textit{sa\Alif ala} `ask (for)'}
\label{Semantic roles sa'ala}

Text text tesxt text text Text text tesxt text textText text tesxt text     textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text text

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Semantic roles and their definition for the verb \textit{sa\Alif ala} `ask (for)' }
\label{table:semantic roles of sa'ala}
\begin{longtable}{ p{1,5cm} | p{11cm} }
\hline
\textbf{Abbr.} & \textbf{Meaning and Definition} \\
\hline
[A] & agent, i.e. speaker: someone A, who says something [UTT] \\

 [AD] & addressee: someone B to whom A says something [UTT] \\

 [REQ] & request: the thing/action etc. someone A [A] wants someone B [AD] to do or that A wants to have from B \\

 [T] & theme: something (person, thing, event), that someone A [A] asks someone B [AD] something about \\

 [UTT] & utterance: something (word(s), sentence(s)) that someone A [A] says to someone B [AD] \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{Abbreviations in the coding frames for the verb \textit{sa\Alif ala} `ask (for)' }
    \label{table:abbreviations in the coding frames of sa'ala}
 \begin{longtable}{ p{1,5cm} | p{11cm} }
\hline
\textbf{Abbr.} & \textbf{Meaning and Definition} \\
\hline
 [A] & agent, i.e. speaker: someone A, who says something [UTT] \\

 [AD] & addressee: someone B to whom A says something [UTT] \\

 [REQ] & request: the thing/action etc. someone A [A] wants someone B [AD] to do or that A wants to have from B \\

 [T] & theme: something (person, thing, event), that someone A [A] asks someone B [AD] something about \\

 [UTT] & utterance: something (word(s), sentence(s)) that someone A [A] says to someone B [AD] \\
\hline
     \end{longtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(Naturally the tables shall not be exaclty the same)

any ideas why this error in the numbering?

thank you!

Comment: Don't nest `table` and `longtable`.  Use one or the other at a time.

Comment: if I delete `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` how can I insert the caption of the table?

Comment: Change `longtable` to `tabular` in your code.

Comment: but I need a `longtable` because the table shall go over two pages...

Comment: you are right with only `tabular`it works - unfortunately I need a `longtable`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the dreadful `table` environment outside of `longtable` (the table is meant to break across pages, not to float away) and use `\caption{...}\label{...}\endfirsthead` if your caption is meant to be at the top, e.g.

```
\begin{longtable}{ p{1,5cm} | p{11cm} }
  \caption{Semantic roles and their definition for the verb \textit{sa\Alif ala} `ask (for)' }
  \label{table:semantic roles of sa'ala}
\endfirsthead
\hline
... more table content here
\end{longtable}
```

Why is the table number wrong? The reason is that `longtable` automatically increases the table counter, regardless whether there is a caption or not. (There's a clear `\refstepcounter{table}` statement after `\def\LT@array` in `longtable.sty`)

Using `\begin{table}\caption{...}\begin{longtable}...` will increase the table counter twice, the first one by `\caption` and the 2nd one by `longtable` again.

Applying this wrong wrapping over and over again, the table counter will be off the real value.

Here's the full code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{semtrans}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\chapter{The analyzed roots and verbs}
\label{chap-AnalyzedRootsAndVerbs}
\chapter{Root S\Alif L `ask (for)'}
\label{chap-RootS'L}

\section{Verbal types and tokens of the root S\Alif L in the Qur'an}
\label{sec-Types and Tokens of the root S'L}


\section{The root in the Dictionaries of CA}
\label{S'L_in_CA_Dictionaries}

\section{Form I – the verb \textit{sa\Alif ala} `ask (for)'}
\label{FormI_sa'ala_ask(for)}

\subsection{Semantic roles of the verb \textit{sa\Alif ala} `ask (for)'}
\label{Semantic roles sa'ala}

Text text tesxt text text Text text tesxt text textText text tesxt text     textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text textText text tesxt text text

\begin{longtable}{ p{1,5cm} | p{11cm} }
  \caption{Semantic roles and their definition for the verb \textit{sa\Alif ala} `ask (for)' }
  \label{table:semanticrolesofsaala}
\endfirsthead
\hline
\textbf{Abbr.} & \textbf{Meaning and Definition} \\
\hline
[A] & agent, i.e. speaker: someone A, who says something [UTT] \\

 [AD] & addressee: someone B to whom A says something [UTT] \\

 [REQ] & request: the thing/action etc. someone A [A] wants someone B [AD] to do or that A wants to have from B \\

 [T] & theme: something (person, thing, event), that someone A [A] asks someone B [AD] something about \\

 [UTT] & utterance: something (word(s), sentence(s)) that someone A [A] says to someone B [AD] \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{ p{1,5cm} | p{11cm} }
 \caption{Abbreviations in the coding frames for the verb \textit{sa\Alif ala} `ask (for)' }
 \label{table:abbreviationsinthecodingframesofsaala}
\endfirsthead

\hline
\textbf{Abbr.} & \textbf{Meaning and Definition} \\
\hline
 [A] & agent, i.e. speaker: someone A, who says something [UTT] \\

 [AD] & addressee: someone B to whom A says something [UTT] \\

 [REQ] & request: the thing/action etc. someone A [A] wants someone B [AD] to do or that A wants to have from B \\

 [T] & theme: something (person, thing, event), that someone A [A] asks someone B [AD] something about \\

 [UTT] & utterance: something (word(s), sentence(s)) that someone A [A] says to someone B [AD] \\
\hline
     \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

A comment about the labels: It's better to use labels without any spaces and latin letters and numbers only.

Comment: Was the problem caused by the combination of `table` environment or by the combination of the two: `table`and `longtable`?

Comment: @csilla: That's fine: By the way, it's better not to use spaces in labels

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer: you mean it is enough to set only the orientation of the text?, e.g. `\begin{longtable}{ p | p }`

Comment: @csilla: See the explanations in the answer, but the short answer is: yes!

Comment: @csilla: No, `\label{thisshouldhavenotspaces}`, not `\label{I have spaces}`